# Calculate meteor_score over entire corpus

Tags: nltk

I understand that `meteor_score` from `nltk.translate.meteor_score` calculates the METEOR-score for *one* hypothesis sentence based on a list of candidates.

But is there an implementation for calculating the score over an entire corpus as well or a way to do it, similar to the `corpus_bleu` implementation?

I couldn't find something for this case.

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2365

Answer (score 0):

I have created something like this for my project:

```
#>>> nltk.download()
# Download window opens, fetch wordnet
#>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk.translate.meteor_score import meteor_score


import numpy as np

def corpus_meteor(expected, predicted):
    meteor_score_sentences_list = list()
    [meteor_score_sentences_list.append(meteor_score(expect, predict)) for expect, predict in zip(expected, predicted)]
    meteor_score_res = np.mean(meteor_score_sentences_list)
    return meteor_score_res
```